# Python define function inside if block or vice versa

Tags: python

I have a function I want to take different form depending on the mode. Should I enclose the definition within the if statement or should I put the if inside the definition?

```
# Case 1
if mode == 1:
    def f(x):
        return x + 5
else:
    def f(x):
        return x - 5

# Case 2
def f(x):
    if mode == 1:
        return x + 5
    else:
        return x - 5
```

I have done both in the past and my static code analysis tools don't seem to complain. So I was wondering whether there is a Pythonic recommendation?

EDIT: From the comments so far, both cases seem acceptable. It depends on the use case. If mode is intended to be constant, Case 1 is preferred. If not, then Case 2.

EDIT2: This question actually arose as I was writing a function. It takes in mode as an input and depending on the mode perform similar operations except it uses a different subfunction defined solely within the function for those operations. As the subfunction stays constant during the running of the function, Case 1 would seem to be more appropriate.

EDIT3: Correction: In the past, I believed it was PyLint that was not comfortable with Case 1. These days, I use PyCharm and that doesn't seem to flag any issues with Case 1.

Comment: In case 1 you only check the condition once.

Comment: The second seems to be more versatile. For example, what if the mode changes at some point? Case 2 would still work here whereas case 1 would not.

Comment: How do you intend to use the function?  Your two examples give different behavior.  In case 1 you make the decision once and the function you get is then fixed.  In case 2 you make the decision anew each time you call the function.

Comment: They sort of imply different meanings. It depends on the situation.

Comment: This is debatable and I will say depends on actual functional logic. As per `Single Responsibility Principle` Approach 2 stays incorrect because based on some condition function is trying to change its behavior and this will be difficult during unit testing etc if behavior is too variant.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to use it for. They can both be used in useful ways. Compare the two examples:

1.

```
    Mode = 1
    Number = 0
    def f(x):
        global Mode
        if Mode == 1:
            Mode = 0
            return x + 5
        else:
            Mode = 1
            return x - 5

    for i in range(0,5):
        Number += f(i)
```

Versus:

2.

```
    Mode = 1
    Number = 0
    if Mode == 1:
        def f(x):
            return x + 5
    else:
        def f(x):
            return x - 5
    for i in range(0,5):
        number += f(i)
```

The first of these examples is best when you want to switch between modes while the code is running. The second one is best for if you just want one or the other. The first function will always give you the answer 15, because the mode changes while it is running. However, the second function will give you outputs of 35 or -15 depending on what you set the mode to in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your function behaviour shouldn't depend on external values, so I would recommend to use the first example:

```
# Case 1
if mode == 1:
    def f(x):
        return x + 5
else:
    def f(x):
        return x - 5
```

Answer (score 1):

1 in 2:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        f.static_mode
    except AttributeError as ae:
        f.static_mode = mode
    if f.static_mode == 1:
        return x + 5
    else:
        return x - 5
```

2 in 1: (meaningless)