# Python __name__() main function

Tags: python

I have tried looking for an answer online but couldn't find it. I am fairly new to python and wondering if you could have multiple main function in a program. For example:

```
ask_user = int(input('enter your choice (1 or 2): '))

if ask_user == 1:
    def print_hello():
        print('hello world')
    def main():
        print_hello()

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()

elif ask_user == 2:
    def print_hi():
        print('hi')
    def main():
        print_hi()

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Is this a good programing practice?

Comment: While you *could* do that, it's really weird, misleading, and pointless.

Comment: This question is really a special case of asking whether you can define multiple functions of same name within different blocks of the same program, which [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45109185/831878).

Comment: Thank you. What would be the best way to call the function? If I want to pass an argument with ArgumentParser(). What would be the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't be considered good programming practice, no. Like `index.html`, the point of `main()` is to have a primary entry point to the program. Even if a particular language allowed that sort of thing, it would be confusing for anyone reading the code and trying to figure out where to start. For the display options, you would use separate functions with meaningful names, such as `print_hello_world` and `print_hi`, and they would both be able to be called by `main()`.

Comment: How can I add both functions `def print_hello()` and `def print_hi()` under `main()` function?

Comment: Note that, if you define a function inside another function, you can only use it from within the function it lives in. Python developers mostly use nested functions for very specific functions that are irrelevant to the rest of the program. You have to be very intentional about how you do it.